# How to make page break in XML? (Odoo 10)

Tags: html, xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

I want to print sales order, below the table of the order-line I have a signature for my company so if the order-line reach 10 lines (maximum) I want to make it automatically break to another paragraph.

this is my code, I make a counter to break but it seems wrong because all table break to another paragraph

```
<t t-set="count" t-value="0"/>
    <t t-foreach="layout_category['lines']" t-as="l">
        <t t-set="count" t-value="count + 1"/>  
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span t-field="l.name"/>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <span t-field="l.product_uom_qty"/>
                    <span t-field="l.product_uom" groups="product.group_uom"/>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                </td>
                <td t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">
                    <span t-field="l.discount"/>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: (x.description or x.name), l.tax_id))"/>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right" groups="sale.group_show_price_subtotal">
                    <span t-field="l.price_subtotal" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: doc.pricelist_id.currency_id}"/>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right" groups="sale.group_show_price_total">
                    <span t-field="l.price_total" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: doc.pricelist_id.currency_id}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </t>
        <t t-if="count > 3"> 
            <p style="page-break-after:always"></p> 
        </t>
```

I think the page break function is wrong? (maybe)

Comment: Instead of counting number of sale order lines, you may put a signature block (a div element of fixed height, or a white-bordered empty table with fixed height, or other blank elements) below the order lines table. If there is no enough space for the signature block below the order lines, it should be pushed to the next page automatically.

Comment: thanks. im using another code. thank you for ur participation!!